# Need of re-indexing on search on Drupal site?

Tags: views, cron, search

My client site has a table whose data is coming from Indexed view, sometimes updates made to the data wont reflect in the view table. **Elysia cron** is installed and up running, which should update the content when changes are made.

Then what is need of re-indexing the search index?

I could see my index only 1% indexed even though I ran the cron 2-3 times. 
Can anyone help in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cron by default only indexes a certain number of items each run.  I believe it defaults to 100 items.  The number is configurable from admin/config/search/settings.

The easiest way to force a reindex of an entire site is to use drush:

```
drush -y seach-reindex
drush -y seach-index
```

This will clear the index, and then index all unindexed items.  Be prepared, this can take a long time.

Sometimes, though, if you have some weird custom logic in the node load or field attach process, the search can get caught up.  When cron runs, the PHP timeout would eventually be hit.  When run from drush, you would see no progress running.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MPD, but my question is how often re-indexing is needed for a site? If cron is up running then it should take care of it, why do we need to manually re-index the content?

Comment: The issue sounds like the index isn't built yet.  If just using cron, it can take a while to index a large site.  Node save will mark it as needing to be reindexed, so no worry there.  When I see a site at low percentage indexing, I always manually rebuild fully and monitor.

Comment: problem here was cron configuration, it was not set up properly, thats why it was not able to index the content and I have to manually index the content again and again. I have configured cron correctly, now I think, problem will be solved as search is getting indexed on cron run.